# After retrieving the onclick source, can't use methods of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is the content of "myPlugin.js":

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function (options) {
    // retrieve somespan
    somespan.html("<a href="#" onclick="javascript: SelectLink(this);"></a>");
})(jQuery);

function SelectLink(element) {
    console.log(element);
    if (element.parent("span").parent("li.clickable")) {
        alert("is clickable");
    } else {
        alert("is not clickable");
    }
}
```

When I click the link element we created inside the div , the console gives me:

```
TypeError: element.parent is not a function
<a onclick="javascript: SelectLink(this);" href="#">
```

So it knows the element from which we departed, but I can't do anything further with it? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here element is a dom element reference not a jQuery oject so there is no method called `parent()` in it.

You can get the jQuery wrapper for the element and call the method on the wrapper

```
function SelectLink(element) {
    console.log(element);
    var $element = $(element);
    if ($element.parent("span").parent("li.clickable")) {
        alert("is clickable");
    } else {
        alert("is not clickable");
    }
}
```

---

Since you are working on a plugin, instead of using inlined event handlers use jQuery event handlers like

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyPlugin = function (options) {

        var $a = $('<a href="#"></a>');
        somespan.html($a);
        $a.click(SelectLink)
    }

    function SelectLink(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        //if ($this.closest("li.clickable").length) {
        if ($this.parent("span").parent("li.clickable").length) {
            alert("is clickable");
        } else {
            alert("is not clickable");
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @Wishy if the use wants to make sure the target is grand child of the `clickable` not just a descendant at any level...  if you see I have suggested `.closest()` which is a better approach than `parents()`

Comment: "if the use wants to make sure the target is grand child of the clickable not just a descendant at any level..." True then!
"if you see I have suggested .closest() which is a better approach than parents()"
In this scenario parents() is better than closest() since we can be sure that the current element can never be li.clickable it has to be parents. So we will avoid that extra condition of current element.